# Display multidimensional array as unordered list using keys and values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, html-lists

So I have array like this one.

```
[
    '0020098238 - Address 1' => [
        '20011045 - 1',
        '20011880 - 2',
        '20014727 - 3',
        '20015506 - 4'
    ],
    '0020011189 - Address 2' => [
        '20012490 - 11',
        '20018679 - 22',
        '20023569 - 33',
        '20028843 - 44'
    ],
    '0020102015 - Address 3' => [
        '20008315 - 55',
        '20008689 - 66',
        '20021267 - 77',
        '20032518 - 88'
    ]
]
```

Now, I want to make foreach or implode or something else and as result get list like this one

- 0020098238 - Address 1

  - 20011045 - 1
  - 20011880 - 2
  - 20014727 - 3
  - 20015506 - 4
- 0020011189 - Address 2

  - 20012490 - 11
  - 20018679 - 22
  - 20023569 - 33
  - 20028843 - 44
- 0020102015 - Address 3

  - 20008315 - 55
  - 20008689 - 66
  - 20021267 - 77
  - 20032518 - 88

I have tried with foreach($array as $key => $val) and than implode $val but it doesnt work propper. I can collect keys but values from array missing.

Thx

Here is what I have tried (nested foreach)

```
foreach ($user_sap_data as $customer => $destinations) {
    echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li>' . $customer . '</li>';
        foreach ($destinations as $destination) {
            echo '<li>' . $destination . '</li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

but as result I am getting only key of first foreach (in nested foreach)

It is not the same question like [PHP nested array into HTML list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786998/php-nested-array-into-html-list) because in other question there are key => (key => val, key => val...) but in this example is key => (val, val, val) etc. its similair but not duplicated

Comment: Paste your code as well

Comment: just use nestead foreach

Comment: In nested foreach, you have approached, but misplaced your opening `ul` tag. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44195551/5447994)

Comment: Your snowflake case is close enough to be considered a duplicate of any of these:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906218/display-array-within-ul-li-tags https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814393/output-php-array-into-unordered-list https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151690/array-to-an-unordered-list https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865864/multidimensional-array-to-html-unordered-list https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893347/create-ul-and-li-using-a-multidimensional-array-in-php https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650394/output-php-multidimensional-array-to-html-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP nested array into HTML list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786998/php-nested-array-into-html-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this solution. In second foreach you have to get key as value...

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($user_sap_data as $key => $value) {
 echo '<li>' . $key . '</li>';
 echo '<ul>';
  foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
   echo '<li>' . $subkey . '</li>';
  }
 echo '</ul>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

i think with implode doesnt work, but I didnt try :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you approached with `implode`, you can use like this:

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "<li>$key";
    echo "<ul><li>" . implode("</li><li>", $value) . "</li></ul></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

---

With two foreach nested:

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "<li>$key";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($value as $subvalue) {
        echo "<li>$subvalue</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach($arr as $key=>$values){
    echo "<li>$key</li>"; //print array key
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($values as $val){ 
         echo "<li>$val</li>"; // print subarray values
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Your Code - updated:

```
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($user_sap_data as $customer => $destinations) {
          echo '<li>' . $customer . '</li>';
          echo '<ul>';
          foreach ($destinations as $destination) {
            echo '<li>' . $destination . '</li>';
          }
          echo '</ul>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: It is the same result, but I have figured it out, in second foreach I must $key => $val and take $key.... that was the problem... however thx

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with two foreach loops one within another.
First loop will iterate through Parent level elements, and second will iterate through child within it.

```
<?php
$array = array(
  '0020098238 - Address 1' => array(
    '20011045 - 1',
    '20011880 - 2',
    '20014727 - 3',
    '20015506 - 4'
  ),
  '0020011189 - Address 2' => array(
    '20012490 - 11',
    '20018679 - 22',
    '20023569 - 33',
    '20028843 - 44'
  ),
  '0020102015 - Address 3' => array(
    '20008315 - 55',
    '20008689 - 66',
    '20021267 - 77',
    '20032518 - 88'
  )
);
?>
<ul>
  <?php
  foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    ?>
    <li>
      <?php echo $key; ?>
      <ul>
        <?php
        foreach ($val as $key_ch => $val_ch) {
          ?>
          <li>
            <?php echo $val_ch; ?>
          </li>  
          <?php
        }
        ?>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <?php
  }
  ?>
</ul>
```